# Bootstrap HTML printing (chrome)

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, bootstrap-4

I have explored a number of SO questions, but haven't found a full answer. I am using bootstrap with HTML 5. I am attempting to build a page that can fit on printed paper (8.5x11 or A4) for reports. However, I am running into a number of problems in regards to printing.

The bootstrap cells tend to stack when I use ctrl+p and don't keep the formatting they do in the desktop. Any additional formatting -- like font colors -- don't show up in the print preview. The margins are not consistent either. How can I use bootstrap and build a report page that looks the same in both the desktop and printed?

Here is a short example of what I'm working with:

**HTML**

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
   <div class="col-sm-6">
     <h2>Person Name</h2>
   </div>
   <div class="col-sm-6">
     <p>Height</p>
   </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
@media print{
   @page {
      size: A4;
      margin: 0cm;
    }
    html, body {
      width: 1024px;
    }
    body {
      margin: 0 auto;
    }
    nav {
      display: none;
    }
 }
```

Instead of "Person Name" and "Height" being in adjacent columns when printed, they are stacked on top of one another, unlike the desktop view.

Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

A printer margin is likely interfering with the column view.

### CSS:

```
@media print{
   @page {
      size: A4;
      margin: 0cm;
    }
    html, body {
      width: 1024px;
    }
    .container {
      width: auto;
    }
    body {
      margin: 0 auto;
    }
    nav {
      display: none;
    }
    .col-6-print{
      flex:0 0 50% !important;
    }
 }
```

### html:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm- col-6-print6">
      <h2>Person Name</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-6 col-6-print">
      <p>Height</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Yes! I forgot to add that to the example in the question, but it still doesn't fix the printing problem. In the desktop the two column div's are parallel, but in print preview they are stacked.

Comment: Your printer is probably applying a margin. That will cause the columns to stack.

Comment: I checked and that is not the case unfortunately. It doesn't stack in Safari, but I would prefer to utilize chrome as well.

Comment: Are you using the Mobile or Desktop browser? I updated my answer to include a new CSS rule (.col-6-print).

Comment: Desktop browser. I get the intuition with your new CSS rule but it doesn't seem to make a difference. Unsure why it works well in safari but not chrome